# Spring REST: Request method 'GET' not supported

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc

I am trying to make a Spring Rest program, but I encounter the following error when I am trying to call the GET method for one of my elements

*There was an unexpected error (type=Method Not Allowed, status=405).
Request method 'GET' not supported*

Here is my controller code:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/company/flight")
public class FlightController
{
private static final String template = "Hello, %s!";

@Autowired
private FlightRepo repo;

@RequestMapping("/greeting")
public String greeting(@RequestParam(value="name", defaultValue="World") String name) {
    return String.format(template, name);
}

@RequestMapping( method= RequestMethod.GET)
public FlightList getAll(){
    return repo.getAll();
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/flight/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<?> getById(@PathVariable int id){

    Flight fl = repo.findById(id);
    if (fl==null)
        return new ResponseEntity<String>("Flight not found",HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
    else
        return new ResponseEntity<Flight>(fl, HttpStatus.OK);
}

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
public Flight create(@RequestBody Flight fl){
    repo.save(fl);
    return fl;

}

@RequestMapping(value = "/flight/{id}", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
public Flight update(@RequestBody Flight fl) {
    System.out.println("Updating flight ...");
    repo.update(fl.getFlightId(),fl);
    return fl;

}

@RequestMapping(value="/{id}", method= RequestMethod.DELETE)
public ResponseEntity<?> delete(@PathVariable int id){
    System.out.println("Deleting flight ... " + id);
    repo.deleteFlight(id);
    return new ResponseEntity<User>(HttpStatus.OK);

}


@RequestMapping("/{flight}/id")
public String name(@PathVariable int id){
    Flight result=repo.findById(id);
    System.out.println("Result ..." + result);

    return result.getAirport();
}

@ExceptionHandler
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
public String flightError(Exception e) {
    return e.getMessage();
}
}
```

I already tried some solutions, but nothing seems to work. Most of them I saw that they are dealing with the POST method, but I have only one POST method, which isn't tied to a custom value.

The error occurs on this method call

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/flight/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<?> getById(@PathVariable int id)
{

Flight fl = repo.findById(id);
if (fl==null)
    return new ResponseEntity<String>("Flight not found",HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
else
    return new ResponseEntity<Flight>(fl, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

This is how I call the method:

```
show(()-> System.out.println(flightclient.getById(20)));
```

Here is where I call it

```
public class Main {
private final static FlightClient flightclient=new FlightClient();
public static void main(String[] args) {
    RestTemplate restTemplate=new RestTemplate();
    flightclient.delete(20);
    Flight fly=new Flight(20,"Tokyo","Paris",50,"2017-07-01");
    try
    {
        show(()-> System.out.println(flightclient.create(fly)));
        show(()->{
            FlightList res=flightclient.getAll();
            for(Flight u:res){
                System.out.println(u.getFlightId()+" : "+u.getAirport());
            }
        });

        show(()-> System.out.println(flightclient.getById(20)));
    }catch(RestClientException ex){
        System.out.println("Exception ... "+ex.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Every other method works.How can I fix this error? Thank you

Comment: what is ur request?

Comment: what is your client?

Comment: I use Intellij, and I added the Spring support using Gradle

Comment: show(()-> System.out.println(flightclient.getById(20))); where it is called exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you're trying to send a request to this url `/company/flight/{id}`. You've a `@RequestMapping` on the class level and when you specify the class level annotations, the url will be relative. So  the url for the `getById` method is `/company/flight/flight/{id}`.

Change the mapping of `getById` to `@RequestMapping(value = "/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)` and then you can send requests to `/company/flight/{id}`.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<?> getById(@PathVariable int id)
{

    Flight fl = repo.findById(id);
    if (fl==null)
        return new ResponseEntity<String>("Flight not found",HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
    else
        return new ResponseEntity<Flight>(fl, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Comment: It worked. Which is strange that it didn't worked before, and the /flight/{id} was one of the solutions I tried. Thank you :D